# Main differences to be aware of when migrating vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oop, vb6, vb6-migration

I am currently in the process of migrating a 5k line long `vb6`program to `vb.net` I've been doing a fair amount of research into the differences that I will need to be aware of between the two languages, and thought I'd get SO opinion on it.

The `vb6` code hooks into outlook and does some mail processing, its written in 15 class module files (`.cls`), one module, and one designer.

So what are the main code differences that I should be aware of before I dive into transferring it into `vb.net`. i'll be doing this in visual studio 2013 and have Visual basic 6 to view the original code.

Comment: There are far too many differences to provide an answer I'm afraid. Have a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648898.aspx

Comment: If you can get a copy of VS2008, there was an option in that to migrate a vb6 project to .Net. It's no mistake proof, but it might get you started?

Comment: Ah i thought this might be the case, was wandering if there were any subtle differences that might catch me out? it's surprising how difficult it is to get VS2008 even with an msdn licence! Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft UK page with [their general advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dd408373.aspx) on how to handle legacy VB6 code. One word about your specific situation: the VB6 app may connect to Outlook in an old-fashioned way, and there may be a much newer-fashioned way to do it in .Net.